# Do I need a flash drive for Xbox 360 specifically or can I use any flash drive?

Tags: xbox-360

I am going to buy a flash drive for my Xbox. Do I need a flash drive specifically for Xbox 360 or can I use any flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [XBbox 360 site](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive), you can purchase either specially formatted SanDisk USB drives of 8 or 16 GB or unformatted USB drives from any company in sizes from 1 to 32 GB. You can use a larger drive but the Xbox will not utilize more than 32 GB.

If the drive does not have at least 1 GB of space, it will not be recognized.

If you don't buy a formatted drive, you'll have to format it but you can do so by plugging it in and pressing the Guide button on your controller then going to Settings and System Settings.

Select the "Storage" or "Memory" option and then "USB Storage Device".
You can then choose to either "Configure Now", which will erase and configure it with default settings or "Customize", which allows you to limit the Xbox format to only part of the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You may use any flash drive that is 4 Gb < x < 32 gb. They have more specifications on their site regarding speed, etc.